# Por que um método privado não entra na documentação em Java?

Tags: java, documentação, javadoc, visibilidade

Por que quando um método tem um `void` como modificador ele não aparece na documentação?

Assim que eu coloquei o `public` ele apareceu na documentação. Existe mais algum modificador que interfira nisso?

Comment: Só por uma questão de pedantismo, `void` não é modificador no sentido usual da palavra. Ele está muito mais intrinsicamente ligado ao retorno do método. Normalmente se diz de modificador: se é de classe ou de instância, ou modificador de acesso `public`/`protected`/`private`/`package protected`

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

`void` não vai mudará qualquer coisa, é só um indicador que o método não gera um resultado.

O que é privado é detalhe de implementação, é algo que pode ser mudado a qualquer momento sem prévio aviso. Você não pode chamar o que é privado, então não porque ter conhecimento de como ele funciona, não tem porque documentar.

É possível documentar os membros privados com a opção [`-private`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/javadoc/javadoc-command.html#GUID-EAAAE17F-E540-42A0-B22B-4D2B2FD3E4D2).

Answer (score 4):

O default do gerador de documentação é a opção `-protected`, ou seja, apenas as classes, métodos e campos `public` e `protected` serão documentados. Se quiser documentação de todos as classes, métodos e campos, use a opção `-private`. Como já respondido pelo Maniero, isso não tem nada a ver com o `void`.

Documentação sobre o gerador de documentação: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javadoc.htm)

Comment: então oque realmente faz a diferença na hora de documentar é sim o modificador